# Is it the right way to say "It is new and air-conditioned?"

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction

So, I came across the word "climatise," which means air conditioned in English. The subject of my sentence is feminine (la cantine) and I think that the sentence should be written in the following manner:

"C'est nouvelle et climatisé."

I looked up the Internet (E-Books) and found that the authors like to use the phrase "avec air climatisé." If my translation is wrong, how can I use this phrase (if it has any relation to air conditioning)?

Comment: Make sure you add accents to your words! (climatis**é**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> La cantine/elle est nouvelle et climatisée.
>
> La cantine/elle est nouvelle et a l'air conditionné.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, only saying "climatisé(e)" is just fine if the context is understood.

When you use "C'est," your subject becomes neutral. So even though you're referring to the 'cantine,' you would say:

> C'est **nouveau** et climatisé.

But you could also say, after already referring to the 'cantine' :

> **Elle** est nouvelle et climatisé**e**.